# Is there a way to change the lightning input placeholder color?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-experience, css, lwc-dom

```
                        message-when-pattern-mismatch="First Name accepts only characters(a-z)"
                        message-when-value-missing="First Name is required"
                        class="custom-input"
                        required></lightning-input>
```

Hi all, just wondering is there any way that I can change the color of placeholder, for example, change it to red, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only attributes you can change are listed in the [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#Styling-Hooks-Overview) for input. You can only change the colors for the background, border, and text, both when focused and not focused. You can't change other colors, such as the placeholder color.

Comment: got it thanks for your help